# PSQL + javascript server, 'relation does not exist' when sending a request from Postman

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, postman, psql

I have a very basic sql file, the code:

```
\c postgres
\c parky
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS project2;
CREATE DATABASE project2;
\c  project2

CREATE TABLE userwk(
    firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(50),
    username VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE workshop(
worktitle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
workdate VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
worklocation VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

this is used by my Javascript server:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


app.set("port", 8080);


app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: "project1"
};
const pool = new Pool(config);


//Create user
app.post("/create-user", async (req, res) => {
  const UN = req.body.username;
  const FN = req.body.firstname;
  const LN = req.body.lastname;
  const EM = req.body.email;

  if(UN == undefined || FN == undefined  || LN == undefined  || EM == undefined){
    const data2 = { error: "parameters not given" };
        res.json(data2);
  }
  
    try {
      const template = "SELECT * FROM userwk WHERE userwk.username = $1";
  
      const response = await pool.query(template, [UN]);
  //if the entry already exists
      if (response.rowCount != 0) {
        const data1 = { status: "username taken" };
        res.json(data1);
      }
  
      else if (response.rowCount == 0) {
        //else if attendee and workshop doesn't exist
        //INSERT the entry
        const template1 = "INSERT INTO userwk(username, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)";
        const response1 = await pool.query(template1, [UN, FN, LN, EM]);
  
        const data2 = { status: "user added" }
        res.json(data2);
      }
  
    } catch (err) {
      //if attendee and workshop already exists
      const data3 = { status: "user added" }
      res.json(data3);
      console.log(err);
  
    }
  
  });
//server start
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/`);
  // eslint-disable-line no-console
});
```

The keys passed through Postman are:

```
username : ann
firstname : Ann
lastname : Mulkern
email : mulkern@gmail.com
```

But every time I try to insert these values into the table, I get this error:

```
error: relation "userwk" does not exist
```

Referring to this line:

```
 try {
      const template = "SELECT * FROM userwk WHERE userwk.username = $1";
  
      const response = await pool.query(template, [UN]);
```

But in PSQL, when I enter the select statement, it works fine and the table "userwk" is there in the database 'project2', and my .env has the login info for 'project2'.

I feel like the issue is somewhere here:

```
\c postgres
\c parky
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS project2;
CREATE DATABASE project2;
\c  project2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my configuration:

```
const config = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: "project1"
};
```

where database needed to be "project2".